# Lastest version of Expo gives errors on start

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

When I try to run the lastest update of the Expo application (released 9 jan 2019), I get the following errors:

[image]

This is before I even start my own project. I am running the Expo app on an Android device. Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

What solved the problem for me was to clear the data for the app.

If you are wondering how to do that, here is a guide: [How to clear cache and app data in Android](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-clear-app-cache-and-app-data-in-android-6-0-marshmallow/)

Comment: FYI, that's because EXPO client installed in your phone/simulator does not match the EXPO version of your app.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that